# summing a column in a dataframe after using Grouper

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of daily data (multiple rows per day), which I have grouped below into monthly data. the column 'Net' contains floats - I would like to chart the sum of the Net column for each month but using the below I get:

'TimeGrouper' object has no attribute 'sum'

```
df.groupby((pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')).sum()[['Net']]).unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=False,figsize=(10,8),legend=False)
```

plt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need chain `.sum` method after column specified after `groupby` like:

```
(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'))['Net']
   .sum()
   .unstack()
   .plot(kind='bar',stacked=False,figsize=(10,8),legend=False))
```